# how to convert lists to tuples in python to avoid hashable list error?

Tags: python, list, tuples

i am trying to add a pair of values to the set function which only takes immutable objects. i want to pass only tuples into it. i have list which now i want to convert to tuples. i have tried something like `tuple(a)` but it did not work. it gave an error **unhashable lists**. how can i convert my original data which is a list to tuple in the loop which is shown below in the code? at the end i want to add all the values to the set object.

**code**

```
waitfor = set()
    print "in scout"
    for a in self.acceptors:
      tuple(a)  
      self.sendMessage(a[self.port],a[self.proc],  {'msg_type':'P1a', 'msg':P1aMessage(self.id, self.ballot_number).__dict__})
      waitfor.add(a)
```

**original data**

```
[[u'3.0', 9004], [u'3.1', 9008]]
```

Comment: `a = tuple(a)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a tuple of tuples, so:

```
a = tuple(tuple(p) for p in a)
```

Comment: I think it's just a typolocial error, they forget to assign `tuple(a)` back to `a`? `a` needs to be the `tuple` because that is what is added to the `set`

Comment: Do you mean `a = tuple(tuple(p) for p in self.acceptors)`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Maybe, but surely it's better to use a regular `for` loop in case because they are not just building a `list`/`tuple`?